# How do I overload a function with named parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function which I want to be able to pass normal arguments and keyword (named) arguments. Yet, whenever I try doing the overload I get an error.

I tried overloading the function this way:

```js
function myFunc({name, surname, age}: myFuncParams): string;
function myFunc(name: string, surname?: string, age?: number): string;
function myFunc(nameOrObj: string | myFuncParams, surname?: string, age?: number): string {
// do something and return a string
  return ""
};
```

Where:

```js
interface myFuncParams {
  name: string,
  surname?: string,
  age?: number
}
```

Of course this is a simplification of a bit more complicated case; but the idea here is to be able to pass name and age, for example; without having to move surname or doing the following:

```js
myFunc("Foo", null, 111);
```

And just doing:

```js
myFunc({name:"Foo", age:111});
```

I get the following error:

```js
function myFunc({name, surname?, age?}: myFuncParams): string;
//        ^: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature. (2394)
function myFunc(name: string, surname?: string, age?: number): string;
function myFunc(nameOrObj: string | myFuncParams, surname?: string, age?: number): string {
// do something and return a string
  return ""
};
```

Typescript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8BiBXECAKcUcqAzsgN4CwAUMsiCRAFzKlhSgDmANLfaWxRGqCAH5W7TiF79kcLuNYhsqAEbRaAX1q0YuBGGAB7EGiwGAFBREQebIbfsKIW1hhx5CxMgEpJHNwA3HoGRqbmngiWtgHSvILCTBJsgTI8Likq6tD+qfEhNPp44WYeVrYA8lCVagBWcdzIAD6RBt4kpDyJsfncGYrKqhpQeVJN1HTIUBBgjsgARAvaQUA):

Edit:
as @jonrsharpe's pointed:

```js
function myFunc({name, surname, age}: myFuncParams): string;
function myFunc(name: string, surname?: string, age?: number): string;
function myFunc(nameOrObj: string | myFuncParams,surname?: string,age?: number): string {
  return ""
};
```

Forgot to mark surname and age as optional in the final declaration.

Comment: What do you think `{name, surname?, age?}` is doing? That's a _value_, not a type - you're destructuring. Also `null` is neither a string nor undefined - otherwise, what you have [works](https://tsplay.dev/wgAb6m).

Comment: Aaah, I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
function myFunc(opts: myFuncParams): string;
function myFunc(name: string, surname?: string, age?: number): string;
function myFunc(nameOrObj: string | myFuncParams, surname?: string, age?: number): string {
// do something and return a string
  return ""
};
```

Comment: Yeah, this works but it isn't what I was looking for, I wanted the destructuring.
@jonrsharpe s answer solved it!
Thanks tho!

Comment: You can't destructure in an argument like that, but (also) that's not how overloading works. Each version of the overloaded methods has to "fit" into the final version. You'd do the destructuring and figure out what was passed inside the function.